What does the superscript asterisk mean after the reopen count?
I see a superscript asterisk after this reopen count on Can one use one's Starlink dish in a commercial plane?:

What does the superscript asterisk mean after the reopen count?

TL;DR: it means you have already voted to reopen the question.
